# default locale change, version 5.0.1 -> 5.1

Tags: qooxdoo

(sorry my english) Hi.

With 5.0.1, the default short date format for locale "es" (in config.json) return this date format "10/01/2017"

With 5.1, the default short date format for locale "es" (in config.json) return this date format "10 ene. 2017".

I think is a coherent change. But I need keep working with the old format. So, where I must touch to get the old format in a entire new 5.1 qooxdoo project?
I mean, where this locale format is defined? I was trying found where but I can't.
Or any other solution.

thanks

Comment: 5.1 isn't released yet. Could you provide a short playground pasteable snippet that reproduces the issue? I've updated the CLDR stuff to be in sync with latest upstream, but it seems like there are some changes that are not that backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet works for us

```
        this._localeManager = qx.locale.Manager.getInstance();
        this._localeManager.addLocale("el", {
            "cldr_date_format_short": "dd/MM/yyyy" // Override short date format for Greek
        });
```

Comment: Hi. In Application.js I put  this._localeManager = qx.locale.Manager.getInstance();
 this._localeManager.addLocale("es", {"cldr_date_format_short": "dd/MM/yyyy"}). Nothing change. Please some extra detail. Thanks

Comment: now I realize, all datefields by default are using the medium date format, not short. Using qx.locale.Manager.getInstance().addLocale("es", {"cldr_date_format_medium": "d/M/yyyy"}), now is working. Thanks